# Using a templated parameter's value_type

Tags: c++, templates, std

How is one supposed to use a std container's value_type?
I tried to use it like so:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class TSContainer {
private:
        T container;
public:
        void push(T::value_type& item)
        {
                container.push_back(item);
        }
        T::value_type pop()
        {
                T::value_type item = container.pop_front();
                return item;
        }
};
int main()
{
        int i = 1;
        TSContainer<vector<int> > tsc;
        tsc.push(i);
        int v = tsc.pop();
}
```

But this results in:

```
prog.cpp:10: error: ‘T::value_type’ is not a type
prog.cpp:14: error: type ‘T’ is not derived from type ‘TSContainer<T>’
prog.cpp:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘pop’
prog.cpp:19: error: expected `;' before ‘}’ token
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:25: error: ‘class TSContainer<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ has no member named ‘pop’
prog.cpp:25: warning: unused variable ‘v’
```

I thought this was what ::value_type was for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: When you're writing reusable library code (or even, ever) it's also advisable not to say `using namespace std;`. Just spell out the correct namespace.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It was an example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use `typename`:

```
typename T::value_type pop()
```

and so on.

The reason is that the compiler cannot know whether T::value_type is a type of a member variable (nobody hinders you from defining a type `struct X { int value_type; };` and pass that to the template). However without that function, the code could not be parsed (because the meaning of constructs changes depending on whether some identifier designates a type or a variable, e.g.`T * p` may be a multiplication or a pointer declaration). Therefore the rule is that everything which might be either type or variable and is not explicitly marked as type by prefixing it with `typename` is considered a variable.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `typename` keyword to indicate that it's really a type.

```
void push(typename T::value_type& item)

typename T::value_type pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full implementation of the accepted answers above, in case it helps anyone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class C1 {
  private:
    T container;
    typedef typename T::value_type CT;
  public:
    void push(CT& item) {
        container.push_back(item);
    }

    CT pop (void) {
        CT item = container.front();
        container.pop_front();
        return item;
    }
};

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    C1<std::list<int> > c;
    c.push(i);
    std::cout << c.pop() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly common practice is to provide an alias representing the underlying value type for convenience.

```
template <typename T>
class TSContainer {
private:
    T container;
public:
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;

    void push(value_type& item)
    {
        container.push_back(item);
    }
    
    value_type pop()
    {
        value_type item = container.pop_front();
        return item;
    }
};
```